# copy constructor, overloaded assignment operator and deepCopy

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I'm trying to create a class template for a link-list implementation of a Stack. Now I've gotten the push, pop, peek, and tested the destructor. But I'm wondering how should I add the copy constructor, overloaded assignment operator, and the deepCopy on my code. Here is what I got so far:

```
//  Lab3.cpp
//
//  Created by IvanChak on 4/3/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Space. All rights reserved.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct Node {
    T item;
    Node* next = NULL;
    Node(T t = {}, Node* link = nullptr) :item{t}, next{link} { }
    ~Node() { delete next; }
};

template<class T>
class Stack {
public:
    bool empty() const { return n == 0; }
    void push(const T&);
    T pop();
    T peek();
    ~Stack();

private:
    Node<T>* top = NULL;
    size_t n;
};

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A(const A &){}
    A & operator=(const A& a){return *this;}
};

template<class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack() {
    cout<<"Destructor, deallocate..."<<endl;
}

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& t) {
    Node<T>* previous{top};
    top = new Node<T>{t,previous};
    ++n;
}

template<class T>
T Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (empty()) {
        cout << "Empty" << endl;
    }
    Node<T>* oldnode = top;
    T t = top->item;
    top = top->next;
    --n;
    delete oldnode;
    return t;
}

template<class T>
T Stack<T>::peek() {
    if (empty()) {
        cout << "Empty" << endl;
    }
    return top->item;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Stack<string> x{};
    x.push("Hello");
    x.push("Second");
    x.push("Bye");
    cout << x.peek() << endl;
    x.pop();
    cout << x.peek() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to search for *c++ copy constructor* in a search engine?

Comment: Yes. I know how to do that in Arrays. But not linked-list

Comment: Before you try to figure out things like copy constructors, how about you fix your existing code. Such as, getting rid of all your memory leaks due to RAII not being properly implemented? I was curious why your code ran, despite the obvious horrible crash when Node's destructor attempts to `delete` a `NULL` pointer, only to determine that the reason there is no crash is because all the heap-allocated memory gets leaked.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: calling `delete` on a `nullptr` is safe and a no-op.

Comment: I definitely picked the wrong week to quit drinking...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: every week is the wrong week for that... ;-).

Comment: How should I fix it.

Comment: @IvanChak if you search this site for "c++ deep copy linked list" you'll see at least half a dozen Q&As on the first page of search results.  If you get stuck, post your current code and a specific question.

Comment: *Copyright © 2016 Space* anything posted on the stack exchange networks falls under [creative commons 3](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Comment: @RyanHaining Sorry about that~ That what the Xcode default setting...I'm just wondering how could I fix it. I didn't pay attention to something like this. My bad.

Comment: @IvanChak I'm just letting you know, nbd

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need an answer or not, but if you do, you would want something like this for you copy constructor and your assignment operator:

```
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& rhs)
{
    if (rhs.top)
    {
        this->top = new Node<T>(rhs.top->item);

        Node<T>* rhsNode = rhs.top; // This pointer is used for iterating through the "rhs" argument.
        Node<T>* currentNode = this->top; // This pointer is used for iterating through "this".

        n = 1;

        while (rhsNode->next) // Loop untill the end of the stack has been reached.
        {
            ++n;

            currentNode->next = new Node<T>(rhsNode->next->item);

            currentNode = currentNode->next;
            rhsNode = rhsNode->next;
        }
    }
    else // "rhs" is empty
    {
        n = 0;

        this->top = nullptr;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I wrote this code in a "deep copy" fashion.  I can't think of any situation where it would be good to do a "shallow copy" on this type of data structure; in fact, I think it would be a very bad idea to do so. I don't automatically assume that you are planning on making your copy constructor do a "shallow copy" on your stack, but since you named the copy constructor and something about "deep copying" separately, I see it as entirely possible that you are.

I tested this code, and it worked.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I don't need it now. But I will still look at it and learn from it. Would you mind to give me your contact information. Please send me a inbox msg

Comment: By "contact information" do you mean my email address? Also, how do  you want me to share my contact information with you? By "send a inbox message" do you mean some form of private message? I don't think Stack Overflow has any private messaging system, although the chat may allow something like that.  I'll warn you, I'm not a master coder. I've been learning C++ for about 2 or 3 years now, and the only real world experience I currently have is an open-source project that I am currently working on.  I have completed many private projects, but no public projects as of yet.

Comment: Sorry about that. No offense. Actually, I'm a college student who just begin to learn coding. That's why I'm wondering if I could learn something from you. E-mail address work fine I guess.

Comment: None taken.  My email address is: fearnbuster@gmail.com  Feel free to email me with any questions you may have. I'll answer them as best I can.